# TypeScript return the type of parameter

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in TypeScript to indicate that the return is the type of a parameter, without explicitly declaring the type (e.g. in a generic parameter)? Sort of like indicating that it's a type identity function.

For example:

```
function foo(bar) {
    // ...do crazy stuff to bar...
    return bar;
}
var aString = foo('baz'); // aString is of string type
var aNumber = foo(6); // aNumber is of number type
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is. They are called generics. In your case this how it would look like:

```
function foo<T>(bar: T): T {
  return bar;
}

var aString: string = foo('baz');
var aNumber: number = foo(6);
```

`T` will be the generic parameter that will take whichever type is passed in `bar`.

Also, you don't have to explicitly specify the generic parameter (`string`, `number`) as the compiler infers it from the actual value you're passing in each invocation. So the following would be valid and correctly inferred:

```
let aString = foo('bar'); // aString's type will be inferred as a string
```

You can read more about it on the official documentation:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Oh, cool, I never thought to try it without specifying the type on the call...oops. Thanks.