# How should I type a function to infer the types of a nested object given as argument?

Tags: typescript

What should I type the `inferType` function below to give `o` type information inferred from the input to `inferType`?

```js
function inferType(obj: unknown) {
  return obj
}

const o = inferType({
  foo: {
    bar: 'bar',
    count: 5,
    nested: {
      lorem: 'ipsum',
      nested: true,
    }
  },
  key: 'value'
})
```

I want TS to know that the shape of `o` is

```js
{
  foo: {
    bar: string,
    count: number,
    nested: {
      lorem: string,
      nested: boolean,
    }
  },
  key: string,
}
```

so that I can type `o.foo.nested.` in my editor and I get `lorem` and `nested` as autocompletion suggestions.

This gets me the first level of type information (`foo` and `key`). But how do I make it work for an arbitrarily nested object like the one in my example?

```
function inferType<T>(obj: { [K in keyof T]: unknown }) {
  return obj
}
```

Comment: You can just use the generic `T` to create your identify function: https://tsplay.dev/w6LK0m

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript return the type of parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620733/typescript-return-the-type-of-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `T` as the parameter type. A constraint of object is also useful:

```
const o = inferType({
  foo: {
    bar: 'bar',
    count: 5,
    nested: {
      lorem: 'ipsum',
      nested: true,
    }
  },
  key: 'value'
})

function inferType<T extends object>(obj: T) {
  return obj
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgggvAgllAZgUwE4AqAngA44AUA3qAglhBAFwLUi20BGAhnswOTc8fADQ12kAK5Q4zAKyi27KDng4AJs1bt2AGwh4cAW37oSMCYZFjty1RoRw8EnAu0BfMW9cIA1jiL8AG5cOs58oG4AlKCgWFJgcOjQGNj4xGQAPAQIOAAecDhQajBIHABWOAkAfOQQ5cwEkSxiBnASeFClZRFAA)

I just want to know, the function here is not really necessary, you could just let TypeScript infer the [variable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgggvAg3qBCBmEIBcGW2CARgIYBORA5JVbQDQnaQCuUcRArCyKQRQApvGEATIpgGCEAGwhVhAWzoBLAA4x2y5q1IixkhHCrth-QQF8SVywgDWwgJ50AbhTnnaoGyAgAdHiBhnASAQpKykA) (guessing your original use case is more complicated)